# How do I understand the text file of a bugreport?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, bugs

My phone crashed for no reason. A bugreport was created and I sent it to my own email-address. It is titled `titan_retaildsds-user 6.0 MPB24.65-34-3 3 release-keys` and contains a zip file with a text file in it. How do I understand the text file to determine the cause of the crash?

Comment: How can we guess the content of the text file, either?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman They are structured the same way every bug report is. I want to know what to look for not for you to point me to the cause of the crash.